# rtUpload Failed sending usage report to Artifactory: java.io.IOException: Could not get Artifactory version

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm, artifactory

I have the pipe running and doing all his needs basically.
There is the jenkins file; the job succeeds, but there is a failure in one of the stages.

On stage helm ('push helm to registry')

```
stages {
            stage("Push to Helm registry") {
                steps {
                    script {
                        rtServer (
                            id: 'helm-registry',
                            url: '-----------------',
                            credentialsId: 'sys-bm-artifactory'
                        )

                        rtUpload (
                            serverId: 'helm-registry',
                            spec: """{
                                "files": [
                                    {
                                    "pattern": "${app_name}-*.tgz",
                                    "target": "${app_name}/"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }"""
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

credentials works ok.
helm chart pushed correctly to jFrog repository.
the error relates to version of artifactory version.
Using rtServer and rtUpload for connection between helm chart to Jfrog registry.

Error (in the middle of the log):

```
11:08:13  Failed sending usage report to Artifactory: java.io.IOException: Could not get Artifactory version.
```

Why am I getting this error? Where does it come from?

Still I see all artifacts stored in registry.

Comment: This error usually occurs after providing the wrong Artifactory URL. The Artifactory URL is usually `https://jfrog-platform/artifactory`. Does the URL ends with `/artifactory`?

Comment: @yahavi  Yup. URL is ok according to one of the employees. Should I check it again? Coz what I understand that maybe this pipe is overwrite the same file every time and doesn't create a new version of helm chart.

Comment: @yahavi it's artifactory and then after a random name of directory. If the file is being uploaded but with this error ? myabe fixing the verions not be overwrite?

Comment: the error you see is because of a connection error with Artifactory. Can you try to change the URL to end with `/artifactory`?

Comment: @yahavi It's end with artifactory/**some directory name**/    like this. We can see the artifact in jfrog i'm just saying it's the same version so how it possible to give such an error like this?

Comment: @yahavi We tried to change the URL to artifcatory in the end. Doesn't work. we got 403 error and basically the build after this stage faild. What is the usage thing is used for? it seems like the only issue here is between our JFrog who's maybe sharing usage info.

Comment: You should use Artifactory's rest API URL. To find out the correct URL, you can try pinging to it: GET `artifactory-rest-url`/api/system/ping. The API URL does not always end with `/artifactory`.

Comment: @n1vgabay could you PLEASE advise in case you have found solution for your problem?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem with this error appearing in the CI was probably because **we override** the same version every time.

So, to avoid this exception just increase the version and every push make sure you don't override the same file.

**Note:** make sure credentials + JFrog URL are correct.

Comment: can you please elaborate to which version you are reffering to? BuildNumber version or the name of your package ({app_name}-***)?
Because in our case -BuildNumber is always generated with increased number and app_name-* is always unique because of the timestamp which we are adding as suffix. Thanks

Comment: @VeljkoSbbb Sorry for the late response, I referred to the package name we uploaded to JFrog artifactory. So, if you increased your package name and NOT override, seems like you shouldn't face this issue. We moved to github actions so no needs to worry about jenkins in our case now :)