# Failed sending usage report to Artifactory: java.io.IOException: Could not get Artifactory version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am deploying Jenkins version 2.414.1 in AWS EKS environment using  helm and using below plugins

```
installPlugins:
    - configuration-as-code:1569.vb_72405b_80249
    - kubernetes:3734.v562b_b_a_627ea_c
    - git:4.11.5
    - aqua-security-scanner:3.2.1
    - workflow-aggregator:590.v6a_d052e5a_a_b_5
    - sonar:2.14
    - workflow-cps:2803.v1a_f77ffcc773
    - workflow-cps-global-lib:588.v576c103a_ff86
    - pipeline-model-definition:2.2118.v31fd5b_9944b_5
    - ldap:2.12
    - active-directory:2.29
    - role-strategy:584.vf8e515397ecd
    - artifactory:3.15.1
```

I am  using Jenkins pod templates as agents and executing builds and generating artifacts.

I am getting below error when trying to upload the artifacts to Jfrog Artifactory  version - EnterpriseX license 7.37.14

```
Failed sending usage report to Artifactory: java.io.IOException: Could not get Artifactory version.
```

I tried with multiple versions of artifactory plugins, but still the error is same.

We are using on-prem  Jenkins `ver. 2.164.2` and artifactory plugin `3.2.2` and able to operate normally.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error appears when the configuration to Jenkins is not correct. Either Artifactory URL was not set with /artifactory or credentials are wrong.

You may see the following discussion that might assist you with your issue:
[rtUpload Failed sending usage report to Artifactory: java.io.IOException: Could not get Artifactory version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033554/rtupload-failed-sending-usage-report-to-artifactory-java-io-ioexception-could)

Comment: I used the URLS and credentials which are working at on-prem Jenkins server , only difference is , The Jenkins versions and the artifactory plugin versions